# LFS chapter 5.2. Binutils-2.37 problem

Tags: linux, arch-linux, virtualbox, command, lfs

Hi I am currently making LFS and I am in Chapter 5.2. And I am trying to run this command  `lfs:/mnt/lfs/sources$ tar -xvf binutils-2.36.1.tar.xz` But it gave me the following output: `tar: binutils-2.36.1.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory` 
 `tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now` Is it necessery to run it ? I am making LFS with helping of yt video from Kernotex. I am running Black-Arch distro in VM.

Comment: You obviously do not have a file called `binutils-2.36.1.tar.xz` in the current directory.

Comment: @they I just downloaded it but it seems nothing happend. It still says the same error message

Comment: Show us the exact command you've run, and the name of the downloaded file(copy/paste).

Comment: @Gagan I ran this command   `tar -xvf binutils-2.36.1.tar.xz`

Comment: @Gagan And the command I ran is from chapter 3 as following :`wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.37.tar.xz --no-check-certificate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you have downloaded is named `binutils-2.37.tar.xz`. But the filename you've used in your `tar` command is `binutils-2.36.1.tar.xz`.

Run `tar -xvf binutils-2.37.tar.xz` in the directory in which you've downloaded the file.